# Using getters and setters with user input in c++

Tags: c++

Apologies in advance if this is below the community's paygrade. I just started learning about OOP and English is not my native language.

I just learned about using getters and setters, and the importance of data encapsulation. However, All the examples I've seen online using getters and setters all deal with static values such as the one below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  private:
    // Private attribute
    int salary;

  public:
    // Setter
    void setSalary(int s) {
      salary = s;
    }
    // Getter
    int getSalary() {
      return salary;
    }
};

int main() {
  Employee myObj;
  myObj.setSalary(50000);
  cout << myObj.getSalary();
  return 0;
}
```

I've managed to allow user input by declaring another set of variables and feeding them as parameters into the setters like below:

```
int main() {
  Employee myObj;
  int salary;
  cout<<"Enter salary: " << endl;
  cin>>salary;
  myObj.setSalary(salary);
  cout << myObj.getSalary();
  return 0;
}
```

Is this the only way to allow user input? Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this other than declaring another set of local variables?

Sorry if this is a beginner question. I'm new to the C++ game and am still getting my feet wet.

Comment: yep, perfectly reasonable, just needs some error checking to make sure `cin>>salary` was successful

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you. I can't shake the feeling that I'm doing something wrong by declaring another set of local variables specifically for the purpose of passing  into private class members

Comment: you could wrap it in a function to be able to write `myObj.setSalary( get_salary_from_user_input() );` but that wouldn't change much, only make your code more / less clear (depedning on your personal preference)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I was hoping I could do some variation of ```myObj.setSalary(cin)``` so ```cin``` would feed the value directly into the getter without me having to pass it into temp variables

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the only way to allow user input? Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this other than declaring another set of local variables?

(and from comment)

> I was hoping I could do some variation of myObj.setSalary(cin) so cin would feed the value directly into the getter without me having to pass it into temp variables

I would not mix input from `stdin` with setters, better keep them as seperate methods:

```
class foo {
    int x;
    int other_member;
public:
    void set_x(int a) { x = a; }
    void set_other_member(int a) { other_member = a; }
    void read_x(std::istream& in) {
         in >> x;
    }
};
```

This lets you write

```
f.read_x(std::cin);
```

to read `x` from `stdin`.

Note that there are many ways to accomplish the same and what is "elegant" is rather subjective. Typically you would provide an overload for `operator>>` to read a `foo` from a stream:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, foo& f) {
    int a,b;
    in >> a >> b;
    f.set_x(a);
    f.set_other_member(b);
}
```

Either this (using the setters) or you make the operator a friend of `foo` (to access privates directly) or you use `foo::read_x` to implement it. Then you can write

```
foo f;
std::cin >> f;
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks much better. I think I'll write a separate method for user input then. 

That second example with streams and operators flew right over my head, but I'll add that to my read-up list.

Comment: @儚き戦士の翼 i strongly suggest you to take a look at overloading `operator>>`  (and `<<`), it is extremely useful. See here for some details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/16615725#16615725 (look for "input output operators")

Answer (score 1):

Note that C++ is not a "pure" OOP language, and idiomatic C++ will happily eschew certain OOP principles in favor of simpler and more effective code where applicable.

It is perfectly acceptable, if you want a datatype to just "hold" data, to use a plain old `struct` (with public data fields). Don't confuse the benefits of encapsulation (...of non-trivial constructs, so you can change their implementation internally) with any kind of "security". Getters/Setters or not, anyone can change your object's data if he wants to. Incidentially, this makes reading data easier.

```
cin >> e.salary;
```

If you don't want "just a struct", it is good style to have a constructor that sets meaningful initial values, so that you don't have "uninitialized" `Employee` objects flying around ([RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)). This means that neither your client nor your destructor has to deal with the possibility that `Employee` might not actually *be* one (hold null pointers, or other kinds of uninitialized resources).

```
Employee e( "Mark Smith", 10000 );
```

Once you are at that point, `Employee` should be responsible for anything that happens to / with an `Employee` object. That implies that it should not be somebody else that's reading user input and writes it to `Employee` data fields (via setters or not), it should be a *message* sent to the `Employee` object that it should update its fields, from input or otherwise, as appropriate.

(Consider the possibility of someone setting a pointer member of yours to `nullptr`, or worse, some random value. Your destructor would throw a fit trying to free the resource, and then how you'd debug where that invalid pointer *came* from?)

At which point we arrive at the `operator>>()`, which can be *overloaded* for istreams and your class.

```
class Employee
{
    public:
        // ...
        friend istream & operator>>( istream &, Employee & );
    // ...
};

istream & operator>>( istream & in, Employee & e )
{
    getline( e.name, in );
    in >> e.salary;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    Employee e; // For the sake of example, a default constructed employee
    cout << "Enter new employee's name (on its own line), and salary:\n";
    cin >> e;
}
```

And once *there*, you get an idea of what *data encapsulation* actually *means*: `Employee` is an *object*, not a data container. You should not poke around in it's innards, you should send *messages*.

```
Employee e( "Mark Smith", Role::INTERNEE, 10000 );
cout << e; // Output: "Mark Smith, Internee, with an income of 10.000 sicles."
e.promote( Role::TEAM_LEAD, 10000 ); // Exception: "Wrong pay scale for Team Leads."
e.promote( Role::TEAM_LEAD, 30000 );
cout << e; // Output: "Mark Smith, Team Lead, with an income of 30.000 sicles and a free car."
```

Note how the `Employee` class sanity-checked the new salary, and knew that a promotion to Team Lead automatically included a free car, and did that without you having to set that yourself. *That* is what this encapsulation is about...

---

As for your question "as asked", whether *your* implementation could do read a salary more elegantly, you could of course...

```
void setSalary(istream & in) {
  in >> salary;
}
```

...and...

```
cout << "Enter salary:" << endl;
e.setSalary( cin );
```

And because that's properly encapsuled, you could add sanity checks, change the type of `salary` to `BigNum`, or start support reading in hieratic.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS QUESTION IS A GENERAL ANSWER WILL COVER YOU QUESTION**

So in OOP, making and using only the copy or the **`OBJECT`** is a core concept, the way you are making a single copy **`OBJECT`** of a class is a standard one, but have you ever thought about **`MAKING AN ARRAY OF TYPE "YOUR CLASS's Objects"?`** because in your case the **`obj`** will only hold only one copy of **Employee** but if you use a data structure e.g "Array" for storing a number of objects then it will be a lot easier let me clarify for you

**EXAMPLE**

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g ... z;
```

assigning all of these alphabets a value will be a huge pain but wait you can have a data structure for it.

```
int arrayOfAlphabets[26];
```

now you want to assign values? (you can assign it dynamically but this is just an example to show you that you can just control the assigning of a variable with just a counter)

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < 26; x++){
  arryOfAlphabets[x] = someNumber
}
```

Want to get Values? you can get values dynamically but this is just an example to show you that you can just control the setting & getting of a variable with just a counter)

```
for(int x = 0; x < 26; x++){
cout << "Value of Alphabet" + x + " is: " + arrayOfAlphabets[x] << endl;
}
```

now you have seen the example that making a data structure specific data type can remove a lot of pain of yours now keep in mind for the sake of understanding,

**YOUR CLASS IS DATATYPE THAT YOU CREATED**

```
    class Employee {
  private:
    // Private attribute
    int salary;

  public:
    // Setter
    void setSalary(int s) {
      salary = s;
    }
    // Getter
    int getSalary() {
      return salary;
    }
};
```

and in main what you can do is

```
int main(){
  Employee emp[5]; 
  int tempSalery;
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        cin >> tempSalery;
        emp[i].setSalery(tempSalery);
    }
}
```

now to print out your result

```
for( int i=0; i<5; i++ ){
        cout << "Employee " + x + "Salery is: " + emp[i].getSalery() << endl;
    }
```

Comment: sorry I do not understand how any of this is relevant for OPs question

Comment: I just elaborated that how he can use copies of objects, in a cleaner way,

Comment: welll yes and I dont understand how that is relevant. In OPs code no copy is made of their object